# Difference between spring cloud config server vs consul?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul

I am confused when to use **spring cloud config server** and **consul**.
Both will read configurations files in their own ways.
Can you please let me know when use **spring cloud config server** and when to use **consul**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both serve configuration from remote servers to spring boot applications. Config Server aggregates configuration from multiple sources: git, svn, sql databases, vault and credhub. Spring Cloud Consul serves configuration to boot apps directly from the consul key-value store. If you already have consul in your infrastructure, it would simplify things by not having to run config server.